# How to fetch and navigate to url provided by API using TypeScript

Tags: redirect, typescript

I have a website manager that will return to me a different url for the server that my client should connect too.

So what I would like to do in my typescript function is resolve the first url, read the text, and then open that in a new window. Right now I can only open website manager window with the bellow code.

```
            var aWindow = window.open("http://azureredirect.net/home/workspace/" + this.workspace.id, "Window", "");
            if (aWindow) {
                aWindow.focus();
            }
```

What I really want is something like the following but the WebClient line does not work(this is the C# version of what I would do)

```
            var url = WebClient.open("http://azurejupyterredirect.net/home/workspace/" + this.workspace.id").toString();
            var aWindow = window.open(url, "JuPy", "");
            if (aWindow) {
                aWindow.focus();
            }
```

Comment: Typescript is just Javascript with some extra features, but compiles back down to pure javascript for runtime.

What exactly is it that you are trying to do? Also your title seems to not reflect that you are trying to pop open a new window for the user?

Comment: I am trying to read the text from a known url, and open a new window from the text

Answer (score -2, accepted):

here's an example of how you could do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var workspaceId = '2';

  $.ajax('http://azurejupyterredirect.net/home/workspace/' + workspaceId)
    .then(
      function(url) {
        window.open(url);
      });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```